My computer cannot calculate fibonacci number greater than 46
my config
arch linux
256gb ssd for root partition
1tb hdd for storage
Intel i3 10th gen
20gb ram
i used this c code to calculate the number 40 it gave the answer but when i tried 50 i takes too long even if i keep i running for 1 hour it give no output.
sometimes it gives the answer for a number greater than the value integer can hold in seconds.
#include <stdio.h>

// Function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Fibonacci number %d: ", n);
    printf("%d\n", fibonacci(n));
    return 0;
}

is this a scheduler thing?
i tried restarting and closing all other apps that i was using but still didnt work
i tried in other languages also
python
bash
c++
it still didn't work
help

It seems an object of the type int can not store such big numbers. At least you should use objects of the type unsigned long long int. Also using a recursive function is not efficient in such a case.

It's a bug in your program. Information regarding the numerical limits of the common integer types is typically found in the first chapters of any C book. "sometimes it gives the answer for a number greater than the value integer can hold in seconds" That's obviously impossible. printf("%d cannot print numbers larger than what will fit in an int. Nor can an int hold a number larger than what will fit in an int... that's common sense.

Fib(47) is 2971215073 (and here) are larger than OP's INT_MAX, thus fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2) overflows leading to undefined behavior (UB). OP needs 1) a wider type, 2) an algorithm that is not so slow.

@VladfromMoscow, yes type is too narrow for such large Fibonacci.  Yet "Also using a recursive function is not efficient in such a case." is not quite right:  Effective recursive example: linear time Fibonacci

@chux-ReinstateMonica Although using a recursive function with exponential time complexity is not a good idea. I don't know why text books keep using this example when introducing recursion.

@IanAbbott Certainly Fibonacci is an easy concept to apply to recursion because that math function is defined in a recursive fashion.  It would be a good programming example too to show how a simplistic implementation has very bad (O(fib(n)) performance vs. linear.  What learner recursive example would you suggest?

@chux-ReinstateMonica I have no problem with it as long as the lesson points out how bad it is. There should be a few not-bad divide-and-conquer algorithms suitable for teaching recursion (althogh some of them may turn out bad if they repeat completed work), e.g. root binary search of a sorted array, or finding the root of a function by bisection.
